# read_some() works but very slow, read() doesn't

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Below code definitely works, but not fast as I expect.

I expect my program to read data at very good pace. There is another commercial app which connects to same server & retrives data at amazing speed. Server side is not a problem.

```
class A
{
    //...

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* myPort;
}

void A::OpenPort()
{
    if(myPort)
    {
        if(myPort->is_open())
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    // make the connection
    Connect();

    if(! myPort->is_open())
    {
        return;
    }

    // set the protocol
    static string init("INIT\r\n");
    myPort->write_some(boost::asio::buffer(init.c_str(), init.length()));
}   

void A::Read()
{
    static string prev_msg = "";

    try
    {
        OpenPort();

        while(true)
        {                   
            boost::system::error_code error;

                boost::asio::streambuf streamBuf;
                boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type mutableBuffer = streamBuf.prepare(614400);
                size_t bytes_transferred = myPort->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(mutableBuffer), error);

                if (error)
                {
                    if (error != boost::asio::error::eof)
                    {
                        throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
                    }
                }

                // add to any previous message we might not have processed
                streamBuf.commit(bytes_transferred);
                istreambuf_iterator<char> sbit(&streamBuf);
                istreambuf_iterator<char> end;
                string s(sbit, end);
                prev_msg.append(s);

                string delimiter1 = ",\r\n";

                size_t pos1 = 0;

                string response;

                while ((pos1 = prev_msg.find(delimiter1)) != std::string::npos)
                {
                    response = prev_msg.substr(0, pos1);

                    //SOME PROCESSING ON THE RESPONSE RECEIVED
                }
        }
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error const& ex)
    {
        cout<<ex.what();
    }
}
```

obviously, the problem is read_some(), program doesn't read complete data in one read operation, sometimes it receives 614000 bytes, sometimes very less. 
I don't want to enforce any limit on size of the buffer, whatever server sends, program should read all that data in one go.

Hence, I decided to use just read(). But, now program is stuck at read(); read() call doesn't return.

```
boost::asio::streambuf streamBuf;
size_t bytes_transferred = read(*myPort, streamBuf, error);

if (error)
{
    if (error != boost::asio::error::eof)
    {
        throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
    }
}
```

I must process the data received before requesting next data, Hence I can't use async_read().

Comment: You might want to think about redesigning your program to use the asynchronous functions instead. Each async read callback receives a part of the message, and when the complete message has been received you put that in a queue and let the main thread take care of it.

Comment: Isn't it slower because your thread sleeps for 10ms `boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));`?

Comment: Your code is bizarre. If you get end of stream you are continuing as though it didn't happen. You also seem to be testing `is_open()` endlessy. You shouldn't have to do that. Your code shouldn't be reachable unless the connection exists.

Comment: Can someone suggest me, why would read() not work.

Comment: Maybe it's blocking (?). My suggestion is to switch to `Qt` library, which is well documented, and IMO cleaner and easier to use.

Comment: Your description of the actual problem you are trying to solve is very vague. What do you mean by "at very good pace"? Do you mean it takes too much wall time? Is it not receiving the data as fast as it's being sent?

Comment: "*I must process the data received before requesting next data, Hence I can't use async_read().*" I'm not sure I follow. You can use `async_read` and then process the request more data in the completion handler.

Comment: @David, Yes, my program is not receiving data as fast as it's being sent, I thought read() will solve the problem, but it doesn't work too. call doesn't return.

Comment: @David, Also will it matter enough, using async() over synchronous read calls()

Comment: Server will rarely send you all data in one go like you expect. At any point it may be fragmented over IP network.

Comment: that's right, all I want is my program should read whatever server sends in one go, be it 1K or 100KB size of data. read_some() is not going to solve the problem, read() will. but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user3924882 If you want to read the data in one go, you need to use `read_until` or `async_read` set to terminate on a carriage return and newline. If you want to read all the data in one go, some piece of code must determine where the end of the data is, and you have to write that code. (TCP doesn't "glue" bytes together. If you want it, you have to do it.)

Comment: And how read() is going to know if it's 1K or 100K? You have to provide this information either from header or higher level protocol, you are using.

Comment: I just implemented async_read(), I must say read_some() was more faster!

Comment: @user3924882 Please don't use such vague terms like "more faster". Specifically state what the speed was before, what it was after, and how you are measuring.

Comment: Using TCP viewer, received bytes column.

Comment: @user3924882 About "read_some more faster than async_read". I do not see any reason why asio should be "more" faster, I think that you have

Comment: @user3924882 I think that this is a side effect due to your code, but that side effect is not discernible in the code you put here. IMHO read_some versus async_read is just concerned by your code design, but all things being equal you must not have major speed difference using one or other. Come on, I bet you have a problem in your hidden code :-)  Anyway did you try my answer, it is easy to test.

Comment: And now,ladies and gentlemen,the winner is ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- With TCP you can never be sure that you will receive everything in one go.
- Because you are reading up to a delimiter, `read_until()` is probably what you're after.
- Make sure you're opening the socket with `O_NDELAY`, otherwise you will add 200ms to your write. Do this by calling `myPort->set_option(tcp::no_delay(true))` where appropriate in your code.
- The sleep is not a good idea. Design your code so that it isn't necessary.
- Your code seems to go into an endless loop if the socket is closed.
- You call `write_some()` without checking the return value. You should probably call `write()` to ensure all your data is written.
- If you have many threads you will probably get an improvement from redesigning your code to be async.

Comment: Don't worry about endless loop. I have added here is not complete solution I am working on. Sleep() is again not an issue. I edited my post.

Comment: @user3924882 OK, sure. The other comments stand!

Comment: @user3924882 If you have sleeps in your code to "improve" things, it is a sign of underlying design problems. It is not obvious that the problem is `read_some()`. I suspect rethinking your code a bit would help.

Comment: myPort->set_option(tcp::no_delay(true)), shows little improvement. Any more TCP socket tricks I should apply...

Comment: @user3924882 Now you need to quantify your problem instead of depending on psychic debugging. How big is your problem? What else is going on in your code?

Comment: @user3924882 Obvious but who knows ... Are you testing the release version with compiler optimizations ? Debug with 'stl secure checks' is a pain with MSVC !  
Also try a quick [asio trace](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html)

Answer (score 2):

Do not allocate a new buffer on each loop, do that only one time outside the loop.

```
    while(true)
    {                   
        boost::system::error_code error;

            boost::asio::streambuf streamBuf;
            boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type mutableBuffer = streamBuf.prepare(614400);
            size_t bytes_transferred = myPort->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(mutableBuffer), error);
...
```

to be replaced by

```
    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::streambuf streamBuf;
    boost::asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type mutableBuffer = streamBuf.prepare(614400);
    while(true)
    {                   
            size_t bytes_transferred = myPort->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(mutableBuffer), error);
...
```